# Mac OS X Terminal garbles text

Tags: macos, terminal.app

Not sure what you would call this. Glitch, jarble, destruxxored. But my text looks like this:

[image]

That's my cursor where they grey box is. Pressing up adds more text in random places, and my cursor appears in random places. As I type, text gets overwritten.

I set `xterm` as my color settings. Any other choices prevent me from performing a `find` on my existing text.

Anyone have this issue, and know how to solve it?

I am also a bit amused by the idea that the link `a57.foxnews.cotracker` shows up in my terminal.. perhaps I'm being keylogged?

Comment: To clarify, when you say 'OS X Terminal', do you mean the application Terminal.app, or xterm/the X11 terminal? You might be being keylogged, but if so whoever wrote the malware is hilariously bad at it. Have you googled "foxnews.cotracker" in combination with "malware" or "keylogger" or whatever? ...And finally... When did this start? Did you install anything new just before it started happening? Change a configuration file for terminal input, output, shell startup, application startup?

Comment: I am referring to the OS X Terminal. My google searches didn't reveal much. Its been happening forever, and especially on SSH connections. This one in particular is an SSH connection to Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Either use *Shell » Reset*, or even *Shell » Hard reset* to clear the issue.

Shortcuts are <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Much better. Will try to be neater.